# Were the Avos "Regular People"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, imahot-matriarch-mothers

Were the Avos in particular and other biblical protagonists (e.g. the Imahos) regular people?
That is to say, do we generally ascribe deep holy explanations for their behaviors or just say they erred?
Looking for views of the G'onim and Rishonim in particular and to a lesser degree the views of Chazal.

Comment: Does the Zohar count?

Comment: @Yishai I suppose it counts as a rishon.

Comment: what do you mean by regular people? were they human?

Comment: What about medrashim? Like Rabba?

Comment: @user6591 I really wanted primarily G'onim, Rishonim (although some of the Rabba literature was redacted in this period). I wouldnt mind a sampling or summary of the general approach of Chazal / midrashim.

Comment: This would make a nice list to have all in one place.

Comment: Are you sure there is a dichotomy between holy ascription and human intent?

Comment: @WAF if I understand you correctly. Yes. If one is honest and truthful then an action can be considered mundane and plain or sacred; not both. (of course depending on semantics sometimes it can be both, but you get what I mean).

Comment: I am less sure what you are asking. Are you only asking about explanation of mistakes? Bad behavior? All behavior? And are you really presupposing any source that makes reference to sanctity and foibles untruthful?

Comment: @WAF I am asking if one should utilize normal literary analysis when studying or them, or a different approach that presupposes greatness in all their activities.

Comment: I mean you no disrespect, but it is becoming less and less clear what you originally intended with the question. I didn't realize it was about literature at all, much less literary analysis. Perhaps you could spell out in the question what types of information you are looking for and give a couple examples? (Your answer contains one, so that could be a good start.)

Comment: @WAF i'm not sure how to be more clear (I guess i'm just not writing well). lets say we have the example of Sarah and Hagar (which I intend to add to my answer) simply reading the verses without presupposing greatness on the part of Sarah would lead one to assume that she was jealous of Hagar and acted selfishly (note that Ramban indeed faults her for her behavior). According to the other approach we assume that she had various good reasons for what she did and that it couldnt have been normal human emotions that drove her. Another example would be the brothers' tratment of Yosef.

Comment: Significant overlap: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30900/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most famous case of a Rishon pointing out the human flaw of a patriarch is the Ramban's discussion of Avraham's descent to Egypt in Lech Licha 12:10. Rabbi Hirsch goes to great lengths to expound on that opinion.

The Medrash Rabba in the beginning of parshas Shemos has a list of our heroes who ruined their children by showing them too much love. Avraham Yitzchok and David made the list. 
This may or may not make your cut considering the Maharatz Chayos' assertion that the early Rishonim did not have it. I'm pretty sure Rabbi Hirsch mentions this medrash but I don't see it right now.

Comment: An excellent start!

Comment: he does this by the sending off of hagar as well

Comment: Is it the same as the Rosh in yevamos regarding lech lecha?

Answer (score 2):

R. Avraham Ben HaRambam cites the verse "do not touch my anointed and do not harm my prophets" (Psalms 105:15) in the context of negative assessments of members of these categories. This would certainly include the Avos, (the prophecy of the Imahos on the other hand is not explicit in the Torah, so this "prohibition" isn't as clear.)